# Clever ways to compute progress for BackgroundWorkers

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a Background Worker that executes a query that can potentially take a substantial amount of time (10+ seconds), based on the parameters given by the user.

I would like to provide them with a progress bar indicating the percentage complete, so that the user is not just sitting and waiting. I'm having trouble coming up with a clever, accurate way of accomplishing this.

I'm using the OleDBDataReader to run my query, so there's no way for me to know the size of the data without hitting every single record.

```
    void doWork(object sender, DoWorkeventArgs e){
       string connectionString = ".." // connection string
       string query = "..." // query to run

        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);

        myConnection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(); 

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" -----------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Column Count: " + reader.FieldCount.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetName(0) + ", " + reader.GetName(1) + ", " + reader.GetName(2));

            int i = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" -----------------------------------");
                (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i++); // just testing ideas here
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0).ToString() + ", " + reader.GetValue(1).ToString() + ", " + reader.GetValue(2).ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine(" -----------------------------------");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
            myConnection.Close();

        }
        e.Result = returnedClients;
    }
```

Obviously tracking a count of each record is not effective because in many cases, that will return a progress of 1000%+. What are some other ideas I can try here?

Comment: You can first query expected number of rows (separate count(*) query) and use that. Of course this assumes count(*) query will be very fast.

Comment: Unless you can figure out a way to calculate a percentage, I think the best option might be to go with a marquee style progress bar, and maybe overlay a label showing number of records processed.

Comment: Improve your query.  10 seconds is a long time for processing.

Comment: @LarsTech I agree that the query needs improvement, and we will get there. However, I'd still like to provide some sort of progress to the user.

Comment: @Setsu I like the idea of showing number of records processed, definitely an alternative.

Comment: @Evk I suspect that a separate count() query will not be very fast, but will certainly do some testing. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: If you were try to get peoples names you can break the query up to run different letter(s) of the alphabet so names starting with 'A' may be 5%, names start with B will be 4%.....